# How to make the PDF cut in Python for OCR with Pytesseract

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-tesseract

With my OCR scanner, I scan PDF files of 12 to 15 pages at a time. However, I only need the information from the first 5 pages. Is there a way to add a function to the code below that will only run the first 5 pages of each PDF through the OCR scanner.

```
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "Path to pytesseract"
path = r "Path to PDF"
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()
 
for n in FoundFiles:
        filePath = path+"\\"+FoundFiles[counterDocuments]

        ResultPageNumber = []
        st = time.time()
        for page_number,page_data in enumerate(doc):
            txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(page_data,lang='eng')
```

After this part only if-else queries follow to search for certain words in the PDF to return the found information as CSV later on.

Comment: The inner for loop is looping over all pages, so you can implement a break if `page_numer > 4`?

Comment: Thanks, that helped to solve the problem.